# ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1248

Tags: mysql

Im trying to import my Database sql into Mysql

Im getting below error .

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1248: MySQL server has gone away

I want to know particular error for the line number 1248

PLease help . Is there any packet max have problem . If yes .How we can analyse to recover that issue .

Comment: Size of the Dumb is 32MB .

Comment: Check [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet).

Comment: max_allowed_packet is 1M . But how this is corresponding to the dump file .Is there any dump and max_allowed_packet proportional ratio's .Like any formula for this to check when we increase the max_allowed_packets according to the dump file import . please advise .

Comment: See documentation: [B.5.2.9 Packet Too Large](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html).